# Where does the Android Parcelable interface enforce the CREATOR object

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I am working with Parcelables in Android and I was curious about this error...

> 11-23 16:17:07.174: E/AndroidRuntime(1277): Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.gleason.apahelper.model.PlayerTeam

Of course this is because I am missing this...

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<Player> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Player>() {
    public Player createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
      return new Player(in);
    }
    public Player[] newArray(int size) {
      return new Player[size];
    }
};
```

My question is, when I look at the code [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/os/Parcelable.java) I can't tell how it makes sure you have the CREATOR object. I can see where is requires the interface but I don't see where it requires the CREATOR name. Can someone explain this a little better? I would like to use this pattern in other code I am writing so I was wondering if someone could explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is implemented in the `Parcel` class in the method `public final <T extends Parcelable> Parcelable.Creator<T> readParcelableCreator()`. If it can't get the creator from a specified class loader, it assumes the default 'CREATOR' one:

```
    ...
    Parcelable.Creator<T> creator;
    synchronized (mCreators) {
        HashMap<String,Parcelable.Creator> map = mCreators.get(loader);
        if (map == null) {
            map = new HashMap<String,Parcelable.Creator>();
            mCreators.put(loader, map);
        }
        creator = map.get(name);
        if (creator == null) {
            try {
                Class c = loader == null ?
                    Class.forName(name) : Class.forName(name, true, loader);
                Field f = c.getField("CREATOR");
                creator = (Parcelable.Creator)f.get(null);
            }
...
```

Edit: Forgot to mention that the method makes use of reflection to get a field implemented in a class using `c.getField("CREATOR")`.

Answer (score 0):

Just thought I'd give an update as to the error message you are seeing.

Here's the bit responsible for that, still all handled by reflection nonetheless.

```
public final Parcelable.Creator<?> readParcelableCreator(ClassLoader loader) {
  ...
                Field f = parcelableClass.getField("CREATOR");
                if ((f.getModifiers() & Modifier.STATIC) == 0) {
                    throw new BadParcelableException("Parcelable protocol requires "
                            + "the CREATOR object to be static on class " + name);
                }
   ...
}
```